# Integer range and Overflow

Tags: c, error-handling, mingw, integer-overflow

This is a simple program to convert positive decimal number into binary. I have to report and stop conversion of those numbers which could cause overflow or erroneous results. I found size of integer is 4 Bytes but it converts correctly upto 1023 only. 
I am confuse where the number "1023" came from? Is there any method to calculate so i can predict what will be the correct range, if say, i am programming on another system.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int decimal,binary=0,y,m=1;
scanf("%d",&decimal);
if(decimal<=1023)
{
    while(decimal>0)
{
    y=decimal%2;
    binary=binary+(m*y);
    m=m*10;
    decimal=decimal/2;
}
printf("\nBinary Equivalent is: %d",binary);
}
 else
    {printf("Sorry, The Number You've entered exceeds the maximum allowable range for       conversion");}
getch();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Could _could_ use `if(decimal<=2047) ... m=m*8; ... "Binary Equivalent is: %o"` for one more digit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1023 is equal to 1024-1 (2^10 -1), so a number lesser than or equal to 1023 will have 10 digits in base 2. Since you are using an `int` to get the result, it stores up to 2^31-1 = 2147483647 (31 because one of the 32 bits is used to represent the sign (+ or -)). When you have a 1024 or higher number, it uses more than 10 digits - and, thus, is higher than 2147483647.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the range of an integer is between [-2^31, 2^31-1]. Because there are 4 bytes (i.e., 32 bits). However, if you want to scanf a non-negative integer. you have to initial a unsigned int rather int. The range will be [0, 2^32-1].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the temporary variables `binary` and `m` you use. Because 1024 would take 11 divisions to become 0, `m` will become 10.000.000.000. However, the maximum value of an int is 2.147.483.647 (since one bit of the four bytes is used as a sign bit). `m` will thus overflow, which results in an incorrect result. 1023 or smaller values will take 10 devisions or less to become 0, so `m` is max 1.000.000.000, so `m` has no overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to take a 4 byte decimal number and convert it to a binary string of 0s and 1s.  The method used in the code fails when the decimal number is > 1023.  Here is a conversion that produces a string of 0s and 1s that can be printed using:

```
printf("\nBinary Equivalent is: ");

while( int i = 0; i < 32; i++ )
{
    printf( "%c", (decimal & (1<<i) )? '1': '0');
}
printf("\n");
```

This eliminates much of the code clutter and produces the desired output.